# Why not say"surprise answer"but say"surprising answer"?

Tags: grammar

Why not say"**surprise** answer"but say"**surprising** answer"?

I'm an English learner.Can you tell me the reason? THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean different things, at least to me.

A *surprise answer* means that I wasn't expecting an answer at all, so I am surprised to receive one, irrespective of content.

A *surprising answer* is one where I am surprised at the content of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!